# Stream live video via Flash across a website

Tags: php, html, flash, video

Right, so I'm trying to set up a website where I can live stream a band when they play. Unfortunately, I've nothing to do with Flash so this is a new field to me. Another thing is, I need to stream the video via a shared web hosting plan, and therefore I cannot do any of this Adobe Flash Encoder and RTMP stuff. So I figured, are there any applications which can allow me to stream video from one web page to another?

What I mean by this is an "admin" page where a Flash object pics up video via the computer's webcam, and sends the live video to another public page, where people can view the currently streaming video.

Bit of a strange question I know, but like I said, I don't do Flash and therefore can't create an application like this, and was wondering if someone had made something, or if there's an alternative.

Comment: Not possible with PHP and therefore not possible on a shared hosting plan.

Comment: Mmm, true. My other option, which I'll probably choose, is to host it from my home network, but the thing is I've only got an 18 megabit/s line. It'll probably do :)

Comment: The questions is how much upload bandwidth do you have?

Comment: Oh yeah, true xD with a wired connection, I can reach about 10 Mb/s upload, so it'll serve for the small purpose I need. For now at least. In the future, I'm going to rent an actual server :)

Answer (score 0):

there is an alternative. Use uStream or Youtube for Live bradcasting.
So You can just embed the code of the Video output to your shared hosting page, and the video will be delivered by uStream .

About how to record and send your video to uStream please refer here.
http://www.computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/social-networking/networks/ustream4.htm
And for displaying embed code in website 
https://ustream.zendesk.com/entries/22434927-How-to-embed-a-stream-or-video-on-your-site
This is the simplest thing you can do without coding hassle, and concentrating more on your stuff.